# Start X in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I have been trying for several hours to get to the desktop in Wheezy (amd64 and i386) on Virtualbox but when I execute: `startx` i just get a slightly different looking prompt.

Do I have to do something before I can access X?

Contents of /var/log/installer/syslog : http://pastebin.com/5ZwpbFxR

```
service gdm3 start
service gdm start
service kde start
```

All result in unrecognized service error messages

Comment: Did you install your Debian with Desktop Environment? Does it not load on start up? How come you end up in terminal without GUI?

Comment: Yes- i ticked the 2 options (I forget exactly what they were)- something like "Desktop Environment" and "Standard Utilities"

Comment: No idea why it doesn't load on startup- that's essentially my question.

Comment: Try `service gdm3 start` as root and append the output, if any, to your post.

Comment: May be xdm.  Try that instead of gdm.   More options include kdm, lxdm... dont' recall others.

Comment: Looks like the GUI packages were not installed. Try re-installing your Debian.

Comment: @killermis As far I know Debian ships with Gnome by default. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: I don't know when last I installed Debian, and it included Gnome in the basic, non-customized install.  Maybe no DM was installed, by default.

Comment: i have tried several different version (amd64 and i386) and installed probably 6 times making sure the desktop environment box was ticked everytime- still no joy

Comment: Post [here](http://pastebin.com) the contents of `/var/log/installer/syslog`. This will give us a clue on why the DE/DM is not being installed.

Comment: And also please append all the additional information you provide at the end your post by editing it.

Comment: I have added the pastebin link to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apt-get install task-gnome-desktop`. From your logs, the DM/DE was not installed, although `Desktop` task was selected. This is probably a bug.

Is there any reason you are using `testing` version of Debian? That's why it's called `testing` -- because nothing is quite working yet the way it should.

Comment: I will try that after a fresh install (i have been messing around with it so much i feel it's tainted :). To do with a Raspberry Pi / Gambas3 / DomotiGa / Other project i'm working on- need to use wheezy rather than squeeze.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. A couple of steps and all working now!